# Analogue clock for Windows 7 in the system tray

Tags: windows-7, notification-area, clock, analog

Does anyone know of an analogue clock that works in the system tray of Windows 7?

Answer (score 7):

I guess this is the one:

- [Analog Clock](http://download.cnet.com/Analog-Clock/3000-2350_4-10461683.html)

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot 1]

And the best is: **It's freeware**.

Ps.: I know you said Windows 7, but on the site they say:

*System requirements: Windows XP **or later***

So I guess it should work (I'm not a Microsoft man. No more :) )

P.s. Now that we're talking about clocks. I just saw this one.... it's gorgeous, not really what you asked for:

- [NOVACLOCK](http://www.novaclock.de/)

[image]

Comment: the analogue clock does not work in the tray i have tried before i will write a program myself i think.

Comment: Since the taskbar got restructured with Windows 7 and replacing the clock never was a documented and supported feature (it was more of a hack which happened to work for a few years because no breaking changes appeared), the "Windows XP or later" very likely doesn't apply to Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Analog Clock on Taskbar](http://www.windows7taskforce.com/view/1763) might be what you want. (once it gets fixed, that is)

Answer (score 0):

I would look into Samurize, its a desktop modification program that lets you do a whole lot of theming/system monitoring and has a ton of clocks.